# Print images from webpage on top of eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, png

I'm pretty new to posting stuff myself (usually I'm search for posts that can help me, but this time I couldn't find what I needed).
So please excuse me if I'm not clear enough :)

At the moment I am working on a project where I want visitors to click some buttons to create output.
Each button triggers the visibility (display none <-> block) with an image.

All the images are in separate <span>'s and those are positioned absolutely so they are overlapping. Also the images are transparent .png's.

Therefore you can see the different images overlapping, and thus creating a certain canvas.

This works for now, but I want to be able to send their works to a printer.
I am using a piece of javascript I found. This allows me to print only a certain <div> from the webpage, with its contents.

However, when I hit my print button a popup window opens so I can print, the printer will not put them on top of each other like on the webpage, but it will put each image separate below each other.

Is there a possibility to make them overlap like I did with `position: absolute`?
It feel that it is not that hard, but I can't seem to solve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What your already try? You have some code to share? You can you JSFIddle, for sharing your JavaScript&HTML Code

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have used jsfiddle only once before, so please forgive me for mistakes. And it does not work properly like this (I can't use my images because I don't know where to put them).

I hope this helps :)

https://jsfiddle.net/cwyus31e/2/

Comment: You can add images to snag.gy...

Comment: hmm..snaggy seems to work against me, sorry.
I can't seem to put it together. Maybe I just don't understand it.

However, maybe an explanation works also: 
with the current code on the jsfiddle link every button toggles the visibility of different .png images.
Because the <div>'s are positioned on top of eachother with position: absolute al the images can stack.

I would like to print an image as the user sees it online. (multiple layers overlapping to create one image).
I this possible on print as well?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer!
The problem seemed to be that the print did not use the .css file.

Because of that it forgot that the images should be stacked on top of each other.

Now I Included the .css with the following line in the `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

It must be a beginners stupidity, but thanks for your help, Amina.
Greets!